# Is it possible to get an email address from a credit card transaction?

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart, credit-card, point-of-sale

Is it possible to get email addresses from a debit/credit transaction.  This is broad question but in a point of sale system, would it be possible to get an email from that credit card swipe??  Where could I learn more about what is sent back and forth during that process?  I am talking about a in-store card swipe not an online shopping transaction.

Comment: Ah, [you must work for Home Depot](http://consumerist.com/2013/01/15/home-depot-uses-my-credit-card-number-to-track-down-my-e-mail-address/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, I would be scared if that was possible.

Most systems, only keeps the last 4 char of the card number for legal reasons. So you wouldn't have access to the whole number.

But it would be still better than nothing.

If you wish to know more, you can look into the PCI compliance.